# Mapview in tab based android

Tags: android, android-mapview

Hai, I am new android developer. I want to create a Tab host application . There will be 3 different tab items .Each item is attached with map view. I want to change the zoom label of each map when tab each item. How can i do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each tab item , set programatically the following line with MapView:

```
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mapView.getController().setZoom(13); //set zoom level according to need for each tab item
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this event

```
public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {
int currentTabvalue = tabHost.getCurrentTab();
```

if(currentTabvalue==0)
mapView.getController().setZoom(----);
else if(currentTabvalue==1)
mapView.getController().setZoom(----);
else if(currentTabvalue==2)
mapView.getController().setZoom(----);

```
}
```

I thinks this is the code you want to achieve this.
In this code you fill the value in the place of ----- according to your requirement.
I hope you have got your answer.